# How to import data from IBM db2 to Hbase using Hbase rest API

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop2

Actually our requirement is to import data from IBM db2 to hbase using Hbase rest API. Can any one provide me the details or steps how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to sqoop-hbase import

Comment: our client requires the import only through JAVA API or REST API in hbase